# responsive video slider wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slideshow, responsive-slides

I need a free `wordpress slider plugin` which supports images as well as videos with `responsive`. I have tried anything slider but it lacks responsiveness for videos. Flex slider have all the features but couldn't find as wordpress plugin. Any help?

Comment: Have you asked google ?

Comment: I have searched a lot, but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most of slider are responsive, you can use :

- Try Wow Slider :http://wordpress.org/plugins/wowslider/

This article give free others plugins

http://speckyboy.com/2013/06/06/the-best-free-responsive-sliders-plugins-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

1. Flexslider is ABSOLUTELY available as a plugin - it just costs money. http://www.woothemes.com/products/wooslider/
2. You don't *need* a plugin to incorporate a slider into WordPress. If you know even a little bit of coding, you should be able to add the files to your theme and just manually add sliders as needed.